# pyinstaller, file not found traceback error

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I modified the .spec file with the following

```
`a.datas += [
    ('WORDS', '\words.txt', 'DATA'),
    ('CITIES', '\cities.txt', 'DATA'),
    ('ANIMALS', '/canimals.txt', 'DATA'),
    ]`
```

after `a = Analysis(...)`. When i go to run pyinstaller on the spec file i get the following traceback error

```
`Cannot find ('ANIMALS', '/canimals.txt', 1, 'x')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python37\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "hangman.spec", line 37, in <module>
    console=True )
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 424, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 196, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 281, in assemble
    pylib_name=pylib_name)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 334, in __init__
    super(CArchiveWriter, self).__init__(archive_path, logical_toc)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 61, in __init__
    self._add_from_table_of_contents(logical_toc)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 86, in _add_from_table_of_contents
    self.add(toc_entry)  # The guts of the archive.
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\archive\writers.py", line 381, in add
    fh = open(pathnm, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/canimals.txt'`
```

when its running for the other files in the `a.datas` it doesnt produce any errors, ive verified the existence of the 'canimals.txt' file and its there, and ive deleted and recreated the file and its still giving me the same error, i dont understand whats going on since the file clearly exists. im new with pyinstaller and i was following suggestions from my previous question and now ive seem to reach an impasse. What do i do?

edit: this is the code that queries the program to open the specified files

```
if decision == '1':
    b = WordBank('words.txt')
    bank = b.returnBank()
elif decision == '2':
    b = WordBank('cities.txt')
    bank = b.returnBank()
elif decision == '3':
    b = WordBank('canimals.txt')
    bank = b.returnBank()
```

the WordBank class is as follows

```
class WordBank:
    def __init__(self, file):
        file = open(file, 'r')
        self.word_bank = file.readlines()
        self.word_bank = ''.join(self.word_bank)
        self.word_bank = self.word_bank.split('\n')
```

i get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    file "hangman.py", line 212. in <module>
    file "wordbank.py", line 3, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory 'cities.txt'
[11452] failed to execute script hangman
```

do i have to specify the file path using the os module?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is evident from the error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/canimals.txt'`
```

You say that the file "canimals.txt" exists.  But your code is not looking for a file named "canimals.txt".  It's looking for a file named "/canimals.txt".  That forward slash is your problem.  I'm guessing that you're on Windows, where a forward slash is just an arbitrary character in a filename or directory name.

The problem is further made clear by the fact that you say the other two files work, and you have backslashes in front of their names rather than a forward slash.  Turn the forward slash into a backslash, and I bet your code will work as you desire.

Also, you should be able to remove the backslashes from in front of the file names and have your code still work.  A single backslash used that way is attempting to "escape" the character that follows it.  But escaping regular letters just gives you the letter itself, so in this case, the backslashes aren't doing anything.

Comment: removing the slashes fixed the issue, yes i realize there are backslashes in front of the others but putting a backslash in front of the canimals.txt produced the same result, but now the built .exe has to be in the same folder as the text documents in order for it to use them, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: I expect there is a way to fix your problem. I'm not yet clear though as to just what the problem is.  It would be good if you could show us your installer code and your file hierarchy.  Do you understand what is going on with the backslashes in the string literals?  Maybe you need the backslashes to be there.  If you do, you need to either double them up, like "\\canimals.txt", or use a "raw" python string literal, like r"\canimals.txt".  Either of these will leave you with a string that actually has a backslash as its first character.

Comment: i will add an answer containing the message im running into

Comment: Don't add an answer.  Amend your question.